# Convert UTC time to PST in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I need to convert the UTC time to PST

From backed, I get UTC dates like "2021-06-25T07:00:00Z"

I need to show the dates in Hstack from Provided UTC date to the current date.

I write the following code.

Anyone help to me.

```
func datesRange(from:Date, to:Date)->[Date]{
        
        if from > to {return [Date]()}
        
        var tmpdate = from
        var array:[Date] = []
        
        while tmpdate <= to {
            array.append(tmpdate)
            tmpdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day,value: 1, to: tmpdate)!
        }
        return array
    }


extension Date{
    func convertTimezone(timezone:String)-> Date{
        
        if let targettimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timezone){
            let delta = TimeInterval(targettimeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: self) - TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
            return addingTimeInterval(delta)
        }else{
            return self
        }
        
    }
}
```

I used as follows

```
func getrangeDays(){
        
        let startday = "2021-06-25T07:00:00Z"
        let dateformater = DateFormatter()
        dateformater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateformater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        
        if let date = dateformater.date(from: startday){
            let rangedays = datesRange(from:date.convertTimezone(timezone: "PST") , to: Date().convertTimezone(timezone: "PST"))
            
            print(rangedays)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what the desired output is?

Comment: Here Dates are coming from 25 to 30, According to PST i need 25 to 29

Comment: Why would it be 29? It is already June 30 in pacific time right now. It's nearly 5am there right now.

Comment: I need to show US time

Comment: Don't modify the `Date` itself; a `Date` is simply a point in time. You just need to use a `DateFormatter` set to the required TimeZone to display your date.

Answer (score 0):

Your `convertTimezone()` function does not make sense. It is trying to convert a `Date` to a different time zone. A `Date` object does not have a time zone. It is an instant in time, anywhere on the planet. Time zones only make sense when you want to display a `Date`, or do time zone specific date calculations. (And in that case you want to create a `Calendar` object and set its time zone to the desired time zone, then use that `Calendar` for your date calculations.)

Get rid of that function.
Convert your input date string to a Date as you are doing now (although you might want to use an ISO8601DateFormatter rather than a regular date formatter, since those are specifically intended for handling ISO8601 dates.)

Build your date range using your datesRange() function.

Then use a second `DateFormatter` to *display* your dates in PST. (Not *convert* Dates to PST. That doesn't make sense.)